# How to grab an element buried inside an element you grabbed?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Hopefully I can explain it well enough. I do

```
var foo = document.getElementsByTagName('bar');
var len = foo.length;
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
//Do stuff
}
```

Inside that for I also want to be able to get an element (specifically a class) that is buried deep within foo[i]. My thought is something like

```
var whatIWant = document.getElementsByClassName("name").foo[i];
```

but that doesn't seem to be what I need to do. Am I just not sure on the syntax or do I need to do something completely different?

Comment: I don't use Javascript; I assume you tried the obvious `var whatIWant = foo[i].getElementsByClassName("name");`?

Comment: Note that the names `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementsByClassName` are just too long, so it's arguably not sensible to use them in your code. You may want to use a higher-level API with shorter names.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I understand where you're coming from but it is for a standalone script that the user downloads every time they use it. with my skills it is going to be bigger than it needs to be either way but I think it will still be smaller by not having to include jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost got it:

```
foo = document.getElementsByTagName('bar');
// foo is now a nodelist of all nodes named 'bar'.

for (i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
   bar = foo[i].getElementsByClassName('baz');
   // bar is now a nodelist of all elements with class 'baz' in the dom tree under foo[i].

}
```

If you were using jquery, it'd be as simple as:

```
$('bar .baz').each(function() {
   $(this). etc...;
});
```

Comment: Attention getElementsByClassName is not available in IE8 and smaller. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html

Comment: Too bad for microsoft. They've had 15+ years to come out with a decent browser. The fact that IE9 isn't nearly as horrible as previous versions doesn't prevent me from consigning the entire IE line to the trash heap.

Comment: Thanks. But damn, I guess I'm screwed when it comes to IE. The element I want has a tag of 'a' along with many others and a class. The only way for me to know what info to grab is by the class.

Comment: @townie: then start using jquery. it'll simulate getelementsbyclassname for you, so you still only write the `$('bar .baz')` snippet, regardless of what browser you're on.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware getElementsByClassName is HTML5 (according to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) and so using it means that not all browser will support it.

When you grab an [Element](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_element.asp) from the dom, like with document.getElementsByTagName, you get the same method getElementsByTagName and so you can do:
foo[i].getElementsByTagName("...")
For the collection of desired elements, then you can iterate over that array and search for the matching classes.

Also, I recommend using javascript libraries such as jQuery or MooTools, it will make your life easier.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` can easily be shimed for IE8 and IE7.

Comment: So I can do `var bar = foo[i].getElementsByTagName('a');` and then iterate through `bar[i]` and do `if bar[i].className == "whatIWant"`

Comment: @NitzanTomer so I tried this but it won't even pick up the a tags. All I have is the one iframe (which gets lots of stuff generated inside, lots of divs, etc) and I even tried document.getElementsByTagName('a'); and it says the length is zero.

Comment: As I wrote, *getElementsByTagName* is HTML5 and not supported by all browsers, unless you are using a javascript library such as jQuery, my advise is to have cross browser js code. The elements therefor don't have this *getElementsByTagName* method, but do have *getElementsByClassName*, so you have:
    foo = document.getElementsByTagName('bar');
    for (i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
      goo = foo[i].getElementsByTagName("something");
      for (var j = 0; j < goo.length; j++) {
        // check if goo[j] has the class you need...
      }
    }